# Rails 4, devise mailer using sendgrid template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, devise, sendgrid

I'm trying to figure out how to use Rails 4, so that my devise emails can be sent using Sendgrid templates.

I'm making my first template in Sendgrid.

I can't see how to give links a name. The insert link button on the sendgrid templates page lets you select whether the link is a URL or an email. I picked URL. Then it has one option to complete the https: address. I want to give that address a masked name (i.e. 'Schedule' - which his the link to the https schedule url).

How do I do this in Sendgrid template?

Also, I have a link to devise confirmation token as:

```
<%= link_to 'Confirm account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %>
```

How do I give that token to Sendgrid in a sendgrid email template?

Answer (score 2):

I followed the Sendgrid-ruby docs here:
[Sendgrid-ruby Using MailHelper Class](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby/blob/master/USE_CASES.md#with-mail-helper-class)

Then combined the Devise docs on how to override their methods:
[How to Use Custom Mailer Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer)

In the case of sending the confirmation token, you can create a link or button in your template and use SendGrid substitutions to pass the token.

An Example would be in: `/mailers/my_custom_mailer.rb`

```
 # Overriding Devise confirmation instructions method.
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
   @user = record
   mail = Mail.new
   mail.from = Email.new(email: 'info@example.com')
   mail.subject = 'One last step '+ @user.name
   personalization = Personalization.new
   personalization.add_to(Email.new(email: @user.email))

   # Get the confirmation token & pass it to the substitution in your template
   personalization.add_substitution(Substitution.new(key: '--confirmation--', 
                                                     value: @user.confirmation_token))

   mail.add_personalization(personalization)
   mail.template_id = 'SENDGRID_TEMPLATE_ID_HERE'

   sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'])
   begin
       response = sg.client.mail._("send").post(request_body: mail.to_json)
   rescue Exception => e
       puts e.message
   end
   super
end
```

Finally in my SendGrid Template, I would have a link or button like:

```
https://myexample.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=--confirmation--
```

Notice that the **--confirmation--** is the exact substitution key in `my_custom_mailer.rb`

Comment: Would calling `super` in confirmation_instructions also send out another email using the rails templates. Looks like `DeviseMailer` will send out emails by default: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/8593801130f2df94a50863b5db535c272b00efe1/app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb

Answer (score 1):

You must post more error details to get answer. But this might be helpful.

**Your Mailer**

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
default from: 'your@email.com'

def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user // User
    @url  = 'Url'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Confirm your account')
end 
end
```

**In your config/environment/development.rb or production.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
port:                 587,
domain:               'example.com',
user_name:            '',
password:             '',
authentication:       'plain',
enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

**In your controller**
`UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_now` or deliver_later

**In your view file**

```html
http://myserver.com/accounts/confirm?confirmation_token=<%=@user.confirmation_token%>
```

This works for me and hope you too.

Comment: @pradeep_sapkota - thanks for your note. That's not what I'm trying to do. Sendgrid has a tempting system that allows you to create templates to use in sending transactional emails. In that template builder, I'm trying to put some links. One problem is with making an ordinary link to a 3rd party url - that is displayed as a word instead of the url path. The second problem is giving that template a link which is a devise confirmation token.

Comment: this must solve your problem https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/substitution_tags.html

Comment: Do you know of any resources that help to explain how to use these tags in a rails app to call a template made in sendgrid. The documents refer to the need for different types of substitution tags based on which language is used. Are there any guides that help to explain this for rails apps?

Comment: I do not use send grid at all there must be through documentation about it. I think first it needs data to be render to json and then in template use <%paramater%> or parameter! .

Comment: someone must know how to do this. I have tried to setup campaign monitor(createsend is the gem for rails for CM); postmark; mailjet and now I'm trying sendgrid. The documentation is indecipherable to me.

Comment: Open bounty for Question then any one expert can help you. Since I'm not using send grid and using own created template then I couldn't explain more than this.

Comment: I appreciate the comments. I've done several bounties for each of the previous attempts. I don't think it helps. I'll keep looking for help just the same.